# UInt8Array of image data has incorrect length

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, base64, uint8array

I need to convert a base64 string of an image to a `Uint8Array` to be inputted in a machine learning model. I've been attempting to convert the base64 to `Uint8Array` with this Node.js code:

```
new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64'));
```

Where base64 is a base64 encoded image. I've attached the base64 [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/aryanm5/d75a53405710809b8df23846f73c4319#file-base64-test-string).

Since the image is 100x100, I would expect the `Uint8Array` to have 30,000 values (3 values per pixel due to RGB, and 10,000 total pixels). This is also what my machine learning model expects. However, after running that code, the `Uint8Array` only has 3889 values according to `uintarray.length`. I've tried multiple methods in different environments to get the `Uint8Array` and it's always 3889.

When I print the `Uint8Array`, I see a list of 3889 numbers from 0-255. When I convert the `Uint8Array` back to base64 through `Buffer.from(uintarray).toString('base64')`, it returns the correct base64.

Why are there only 3889 values in my `Uint8Array` instead of 30,000? How can I get the array in the format that I want, with three values for each pixel and 10,000 pixels?

Comment: What is the source image? Is it some compressed form, like JPEG or PNG?

Comment: @Pointy The source image is a JPEG coming from the user's phone camera. It's resized to 100x100 and then converted to base64.

Comment: Right, well if it's a compressed image it's, well, compressed. The raw data isn't useful unless something that understands JPG encoding decodes it into a presentable image.